# When are $f(x)=g(x)$ and $h(f(x))=h(g(x))$ equivalent?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, elementary-set-theory

When solving $\arcsin x = \pi \arccos x$ algebraically that gives us solutions that are not true (since the equation has no real solutions. This begs the question: Under what conditions would $f(x)=g(x)$ and $h(f(x))=h(g(x))$ have the same solution sets?

Comment: When $h$ is injective?

Answer (score 0):

This holds if and only if $h$ is what's called a "monomorphism", as a category theoretic notion. Now, this is equivalent the category of sets to being injective.